# Passing a const reference down a chain of constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, constants

I get a runtime error with the following code, which is a reproducible reduction of my actual code. I am sure I am not instantiating something properly, but I cannot figure out what it is.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    int n;

public:
    A();
    A(const int k);
    int getn() const { return n; };
};

A::A() : n(0) {};

A::A(const int k) : n(k) {}

class B {
    const A& myA;

public:
    B(const A& anA);
    int getn() const { return myA.getn(); };
};

B::B(const A& anA) : myA(anA) {}

class C {
    const A& myA;
    const B& myB;

public:
    C(const A& anA);
    int getn() const { return myB.getn(); };
};

C::C(const A& anA) : myA(anA), myB(myA) {}

class D {
    A myA;
    C myC;

public:
    D(const int k);
    int getAn() const { return myA.getn(); };
    int getCn() const { return myC.getn(); };
};

D::D(const int k) : myA(k), myC(myA) {}

int main() {
    D myD(10);
    cerr << "A: " << myD.getAn() << '\n';
    cerr << "C: " << myD.getCn() << '\n';
}
```

I either get a segmentation fault on the second line of output or "C:0", instead of "C:10" which I expect.

Comment: Works fine for me in [Ideone](http://ideone.com/kOWKo)

Comment: On http://codepad.org/3fgz8aF3 however, they appear to use the same compiler (gcc IIRC)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? (Version might be important)

Comment: Using gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664), I get a segfault.

Comment: Using gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46), I get "C:0".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is in this line:
`C::C(const A& anA) : myA(anA), myB(myA) {}`
myB is a reference. But to what? The answer is to a temporary. `myB(myA)` will construct a temp object that is assigned to your reference. Unfortunately this object will be destroyed after the Ctor exits.
Change your code to the following:

```
class C {
const A& myA;
const B myB;

public:...
```

and it should work.

BTW: I nearly always declare constructors with one argument as explicit. Do so and the compiler will warn you.

Comment: This is correct, reference-to-const will only prolong a temporaries life-time at function or global scope, not at class scope. Also, upping the warning level helps: `warning C4413: 'C::myB' : reference member is initialized to a temporary that doesn't persist after the constructor exits`

Comment: Yes, this was it. I was trying to avoid creating multiple copies of A, and forgot that there needs to be at least one real B. Thanks!

Comment: I did not want to come up with the lifetime change of cont& to temporaries. But after digging in my bookmarks I found the link to herb sutters post about this. http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/. And in there it is also mentioned that it does not work for members.

Comment: I get no warnings with c++ 4.3.2 using -Wall -Wextra -pedantic. I must be missing something; I don't see how this is creating a temporary.

Comment: @Fred: What the compiler does is essentially this.`myB(B(myA))` Try adding `explicit` to the Ctor. Then the gcc will emit an error because of the implicit conversion.

Comment: @mkaes: You're correct. But I would have thought myB would be initialized to reference the same object as myA, not a temporary.

Comment: By the way, this was a toy example. The actual (non-explicit) constructor has several other arguments, and gcc did not warn me.

Comment: @mkaes: Oh duh, the light just dawned -- it has to construct a temporary because they're unrelated types, so it uses B's conversion constructor. I'm not fully awake yet, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initialize D::myC with reference to D::myA, this is not correct because object is not completely constructed at this moment.

```
D::D(const int k) : myA(k), myC(myA) {}
```

Comment: Nope, passing references to incomplete objects is not a problem, so long you don't use them.

Comment: Are you sure about this? If I add a myB to D and use it to construct myC (after adding an appropriate constructor), it works fine.